# sqlite java query does not insert into table

Tags: java, sqlite

Have sqlite table named `good_in` with columns `in_id`, `good_code`, `in_group`, `in_quantity`, `in_VATPaid`

Here is my table example
[image]

and have method to insert records into it

```
public static void inputGoods(GoodsInput goodsinput){
    String goodCode = goodsinput.getInGood().getGood_code();
    int goodBatch = goodsinput.getInGroup();
    int goodQuantity = goodsinput.getInQuantity();
    double goodVATPaid = goodsinput.getInVatPaid();
    String sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO good_in (good_code, in_group, in_quantity, in_VATPaid)"
            + " VALUES ('" + goodCode + "', " + "'" + goodBatch + "', " + "'" + goodQuantity
            + "', " + "'" +goodVATPaid + "');";
    System.out.print(sqlInsert);
    Connection conn = ConnectionFactory.ConnectDB();
    try{
        Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
        statement.executeUpdate(sqlInsert);
    }
    catch(SQLException e){
    }
}
```

Connection class

```
        public static Connection ConnectDB(){ 
    try{ 
    Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC"); 
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:kahuyq.db"); 
    return con; 
    } catch (HeadlessException | ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex){ JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex); } 
    return null; 

}
```

When I copy the printed query to sqlite manager it adds the row, but from java it ends program with no error but does not add row to my table.
What is wrong?

Have also other method that checks weather the `good_code` exists in table `good` which have only 2 columns `id` and `good_code` and if does not exist adds it. this method is accessed from `GoodsInput` constructor. When I delete the method from constructor the other method works fine. 
Here is that method

```
   public static void insertGoods(Good g){
    String sqlSelect = "Select * from good where good_code = '" 
            + g.getGood_code() + "'" ;
    String sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO good (good_code)"
            + "VALUES ('" + g.getGood_code() +"')";
    Connection conn = ConnectionFactory.ConnectDB();
    try{
        Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(sqlSelect);


        while(!rs.next()){
            statement.executeUpdate(sqlInsert);
            break;
        }

    }
    catch(SQLException e){
    }
}
```

Comment: is there any error ? How is the connection build ?

Comment: No error, Connection is built this way                                                     public static Connection ConnectDB(){
        try{
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:kahuyq.db");

            return con;
        } catch (HeadlessException | ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
        }
        return null;
    }

Comment: Are you sure that the connection works?

Comment: Have another method that works with same connection and adds into other table and it works

Comment: Did you double check the connection configuration ?

Comment: How to do that?

Comment: Means address, port, username and password are correct? for establishing the connection

Comment: there is no username and password and the same connection in other method of same class works

Comment: is this path to db `kahuyq.db` correct ?

Comment: Have you checked your output/target folder that you don't have created a new file for the database which actually got the new data?  Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:kahuyq.db");  is a relative path and wont connect to a specific one unless you provide the full path..

Comment: What's the return value of executeUpdate()?
By the way, you should really sanitize your inputs, for example by using [PreparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) instead of Statement.

Comment: I put the absolute path and it worked. But I do not understand how it worked for first method. Thanks StefanE

Comment: no excepton logging `... catch(SQLException e){}` in inputGoods?

Comment: no exception @k3b

Answer (score 0):

Try to add

```
conn.commit();
```

after the execution of your statement.

Comment: it adds one row but if I repeat to add the same object it does not add. Maybe something wrong with table columns?

Comment: Do You have an error ? What is the primary key of your table ?

Have you done a commit after each addition, or one after all of them ?

Comment: I have no error, PK is in_id with autoincrement, I hadn't done any commit but when @Florian Huc wrote I added it to end of execution in every method. And I haven't closed my connection. Can it be the matter?

Comment: Is it in the insertGoods method that you have only one insertion ? Can it be related to your while loop:
`while(!rs.next()){
            statement.executeUpdate(sqlInsert);
            break;
        }`
This loop will insert only once. If you want to insert once for all items of rs, you should remove the break.